# Imports in __init__ file

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, filepath, project-structure

I am building a small project in Python. I have structured it like this:

```
src
  - module_a
      - __init__.py
      - helper.py
  - module_b
      - __init__.py
      - utils.py
  - __init__.py
  - main_script.py
```

**This works**:

```
# src __init__ file contents
from src import module_a, module_b

# module_a __init__ file contents
from module_a.helper import func1

# module_b __init__ file contents
from module_b.utils import func2
```

**This doesn't work**

```
# src __init__ file contents
from src import module_a, module_b

# module_a __init__ file contents
from src.module_a.helper import func1

# module_b __init__ file contents
from src.module_b.utils import func2
```

This throws an error `No module named src`. This should work, right? Can anyone explain in detail why is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, you haven't imported src, so there isn't an src module to access contents from. `from src import module_a, module_b` initializes modules module_a and module_b and uses the  `from src` part to describe where to find them. As a result, module_a and module_b are free-floating objects, completely unbound from src. If you want them to be attributes of src, just use `import src`, though it seems your working case works fine. More detail here: https://realpython.com/lessons/import-statement/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if you take a look here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/keras you will see that they are doing the same

Comment: did you take a look?